# Crear reporte pdf con ireport en netbeans con JSON como datasource

Tags: java, json, pdf, jasper-reports

soy nuevo programando en java y me he encontrado con un pequeño problema, estoy generando un reporte pdf tomando como `datasource` un archivo JSON, pero no he logrado pasarle el JSON al `JasperFillManager.fillReport` para que me genere el pdf, si le cargo a través de una bd, funciona, pero con el JSON NO. Este es el código que tengo:

```
// clase que carga json
public class JsonParsing implements Connection {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
          JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
          File file = new File("web\\WEB-INF\\empleados.json");
          Object object = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(file));
          //System.out.println(object); 

      } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}


// servlet que genera reporte.

public class ServletReport extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ParseException, JRException {

        try{
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            JsonParsing metodo = new JsonParsing();

            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();        
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF/principal.jasper"), new HashMap<String, Object>(), metodo);
            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
            exporter.exportReport();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ya logré capturar el `json`, por medio de una url de la siguiente manera:

```
UserClass mapInf = mapper.readValue(new URL("https://api.myjson.com/bins/xxxxx"), 
                   UserClass.class);

parametros.put("infoEmpNmEmpresa", mapInf.getInfoEmpNmEmpresa());
parametros.put("tipoIdentificacionEmp", mapInf.getTipoIdentificacionEmp());
parametros.put("infoEmpNumeroIdentificacion", mapInf.getInfoEmpNumeroIdentificacion());
```